# How to write one array value at a time (dataframe to csv)?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, csv

This is working great, but I have thousands of rows to write to csv.  It takes hours to finish and sometimes my connection will drop and prevent the query from finishing.

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT'] 
faang = Ticker(symbols)
faang.summary_detail
df = pd.DataFrame(faang.summary_detail).T
df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)
```

Above is only three symbols: `symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT']`, but imagine there are 50,000 symbols.  What I am currently doing is breaking it down into 500 symbols at a time:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT'] #imagine here are 500 symbols.
faang = Ticker(symbols)
faang.summary_detail
df = pd.DataFrame(faang.summary_detail).T
df.to_csv('summary_detailsample.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)

symbols = ['BABA','AMD','NVDA'] #imagine here are 500 symbols.
faang = Ticker(symbols)
faang.summary_detail
df = pd.DataFrame(faang.summary_detail).T
df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)

#Repeat the last five lines 100+ times for 50,000 symbols (500 symbols x 100 blocks of code).
```

So the last five lines of code I copy 100+ times to append/write all the symbols' data.  It works great, but I would like to not have 500 lines of code.  I would like it to append a record one symbol at a time and throw all the 50,000 symbols in there one time (not have to copy code over and over).

Perhaps most importantly I would like the first symbol's column headers to be followed by the rest of the symbols.  Some of the symbols will have 20 columns and others will have 15 or so.  The data ends up not matching.  The rows won't match other rows, etc.

Comment: You can store the dataframes created from `.summary_detail` into a list and then as a last step of your script you can do `pd.concat` to concatenate them into one dataframe (and then save that dataframe)

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Kesely.  Got it to work.  Now trying to figure this out how to error handle null/empty values: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74645315/  If my question was clear, please upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below looping through the list of tickers, appending the dataframes as you loop onto the CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker


symbols = [#All Of Your Symbols Here]
for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.summary_detail
    df = pd.DataFrame(faang.summary_detail).T
            
    df.to_csv('summary_detailsample.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Carson Whiteley.  The code did run, but got an `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index` error when trying to run 30k symbols and no output file was created.  Then I got `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid` when trying to run 10 symbols.  Just to clarify, I am trying to get the file to be created on the first ticker and each ticker be appended one at a time.  So a .csv file will be created right away and every second or so tickers will be appended to the .csv file over hours.

Comment: Hey @HTMLHelpMe, if you're looking to do it one at a time in terms of writing the df to a CSV. Try putting the to_csv() method inside the for loop. That way, each ticker will be appended onto the CSV as it's looping through. Note, you may want to set header to False in that case to avoid duplicate header rows.

Comment: Thank you so much @Carson Whitley!  Works great!
Now I have a related question.  I altered the code to grab only certain columns (`header = ["Column1", "Column2"...]` below the `symbols = []` line and `columns=header` in the `df.to_csv` line) and am getting `KeyError: "['Column2'] not in index"`.  So it writes to csv until that symbols that does not have Column2 data.  How do I have it continue and just put nulls/blanks for empty/missing data?

Comment: Here's another post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74645315/ for above.  Much appreciate your help.  If my question was clear, please upvote it :)