# Continue running code when KeyError: "['Column'] not in index" occurs for null values?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, csv

I get `KeyError: "['marketCap'] not in index"` when there is no data in the `"marketCap"` column for a particular symbol.  How do I put "Null" when there's no data so the code can continue running and not error out?

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['MSFT','GOOG','AAPL'] #I have to put 75,000+ symbols here.
header = ["regularMarketPrice", "marketCap"]

for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.price
    df = pd.DataFrame(faang.price).T
    df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False, columns=header)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this working:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ['MSFT','GOOG','AAPL'] #I have to put 75,000+ symbols here.
header = ["regularMarketPrice", "marketCap"]

for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.price
    df = pd.DataFrame(faang.price,{"regularMarketPrice":[1],"marketCap":[2]}).T  
#adding the {...} fixed a 'scalar value' error as well.
    try:
        df.to_csv('mktcaptest.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False, columns=header)
    except KeyError:
        continue
```